# I wanted to plot space time graph especially Hovmoller plot using the data having date 2018-01-01 to 2018-01-11. How to make read datewise, data

Tags: r, dataframe, plot, gstat

I wanted to plot space time graph especially Hovmoller plot using the data having date 2018-01-01 to 2018-01-11.  How to make read datewise, aod data also

after this I want to plot spatiotemporal variogram any idea how to do it??
Thank you

`sp<-select(AOD_st,contains("l"))`

`space<-SpatialPoints(sp)`

`WGS84 <- CRS("+init=epsg:4326")`

`proj4string(space)<-WGS84`

`data=data.frame(AOD_st[3:length(AOD_st)])`

`time <- as.POSIXct(c("2018-01-01"),tz="GMT")`

`endTime<-as.POSIXct(c("2018-01-11"),tz="GMT")`

`stfdf =STFDF(space,time,data,endTime)`

`stplot(stfdf,mode="xt",scaleX=0)`

This way I was trying
My data set is
[satellite gridded data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nrR4m.png)